# Enter input data to api's endpoint query in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

I am new to React. I want to integrate weatherstack API with my project. Problem is I do not understand how can I input country's capital's name into API's endpoint.

```
const App = () => {
      const [ countries, setCountries ] = useState([]) 
      const [ searchingItem, setSearchingItem ] = useState('')
      const [ showAll, setShowAll ] = useState(true)
      const [ weatherData, setWeatherData ] = useState([])
      const [ capital, setCapital ] = useState('')
      const api_key = process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API
      
      useEffect(() => {
        axios
          .get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
          .then(response => {
            setCountries(countries.concat(response.data))
          })
      }, [])

      useEffect(() => {
        console.log(capital, searchingItem)
        axios
          .get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${api_key}&query=${capital}`)
          .then( response => {
            console.log(searchingItem)
            setWeatherData(weatherData.concat(response.data))
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      }, [])
      

      const handleChangeSearch = (event) => {
        setSearchingItem(event.target.value)
        setShowAll(false)
        }
  
      let countriesToShow = showAll
          ? countries
          : countries.filter(country => country.name.indexOf(searchingItem) !== -1);

      const handleClick = (country) => {
        setCapital(country.capital)
        setSearchingItem(country.name)
      }


      return (
        <div id='App'>
          <h2>Phonebook</h2>
          <div>
            Search a name <Filter value={searchingItem} onChange={handleChangeSearch} />
            <div>
            { countriesToShow.length === 250 
              ? '' 
              : countriesToShow.length >= 10 
              ? <div><p>Too many matches, specify another filter</p></div> 
              : countriesToShow.length > 1 
              ? countriesToShow.map(country => <div>
                <li key={nanoid()}>{country.name}
                <button type='button' onClick={() => handleClick(country)}>Show</button></li></div>)
              : countriesToShow.length === 1
              ? <div>
                  <View country={countriesToShow[0]} key={nanoid()}/>
                </div>
              : 'No results occured'}
            </div>
            <div>
              <div>{console.log(weatherData)}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
```

I need to display weather data below the `View` component if I pressed button 'Show'.

I have tried to create state variable `capital` and set it to country's name whenever onClick event will happen:

```
const handleChangeSearch = (event) => {
        setSearchingItem(event.target.value)
        setShowAll(false)
        }
```

But it seems like I can't access to `capital` variable in the `useState` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(capital, searchingItem)
        axios
          .get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${api_key}&query=${capital}`)
          .then( response => {
            console.log(capital)
            setWeatherData(weatherData.concat(response.data))
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      }, [])
```

because this is the only thing that I am getting when hook makes a call:

```
error:
code: 601
info: "Please specify a valid location identifier using the query parameter."
type: "missing_query"
__proto__: Object
success: false
```

Any hints about how to display weather info whenever user clicks `Show` button?

Here is repo of the project if it is needed: https://github.com/rd9911/UniHelsinkiFullStack/tree/main/part2/part2c

If more info needed please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the hook runs initially, `capital` is empty `''`. You want to call the API when `capital` changes using dep array (`[capital]`) and avoid calling the API when it is empty. Try this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if(! capital) { return;}

    console.log(capital, searchingItem)
    axios
      .get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${api_key}&query=${capital}`)
      .then( response => {
        console.log(searchingItem)
        setWeatherData(weatherData.concat(response.data))
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }, [capital])
```

Answer (score 1):

When you provide no values inside the second argument(which is an array) of useEffect hook, it will  run only once in the beginning. So in your case the call to the API goes even before the capital variable is set. To solve this you can just add capital to the array [capital]  as a second argument to useEffect.